# jquery event preventDefault() not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, preventdefault

I use MVC and would like to submit a form via jquery, but for the mvc built in validation to work in case of a any invalid input, I've conditioned the "return false" of the click event (also tried "event.preventDefault"), in case of getting a "success" json return from the controller.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var request;
    $('#formSubmit').click(function (event) {
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '/personManager/loadDetails/',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('form').serialize()
        });
        request.done(function(data){
            if(data=="success")
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    });
```

I can't make it work...
What do I do wrong?
also, is there any more efficient way to preserve mvc validation mechanism, while working with jquery?

**updated**: If I try to describe my wish more simply: I want to condition the preventDefault of the click event, so in a certain condition it will invoke the form submit, and in other, it won't, and only $.ajax work. 
The second accures after I confirm on the server side that no action has taken place.
There's must be a way, I guess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely because your ajax is asynchronous. Set it to be synchronous and your code should work fine. However be aware that if the server fails to respond instantaneously you risk your user's browser freezing up.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem as OP last week. I'm quite certain this is the solution.

Comment: If you mean by doing what Curt suggest above, then it doesn't work for me... tnks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this last week. You need to set `async:false` on your `$.ajax` function. Your default event is probably being ran before the `ajax` response has had chance to prevent this. This is because AJAX runs asynchronously. Setting `async:false` will prevent this from happening. But as [@Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10231499/370103) has pointed out, this does mean your page can freeze if the response fails.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var request;
    var preventDefault = false;
    $('#formSubmit').click(function (event) {
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '/personManager/loadDetails/',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('form').serialize()
            , async: false
        });
        request.done(function (data) {
            if (data == "success")
                preventDefault = true;
        });

        if (preventDefault){
           e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: tnks, but not working. The problem is that the click event is never prevented when I condition it either way.

Comment: @Tall Have you added `async:false`?

Comment: Apparently it is the solution. tnks Curt!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use, jQuery validate? Do you need server side specific validation?
I realize that you're already using mvc built in validation, but since you're using jQuery to submit the form you might as well using for validation. Just a suggestion since that way you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {},
        messages: {}
    });
    var request;
    $('#formSubmit').click(function (event) {
            if($('form').valid()){
                request = $.ajax({
                    url: '/personManager/loadDetails/',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('form').serialize()
                });
                request.done(function(data){
                    if(data=="success")
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });                     
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: I'd rather to stick with MVC validation.. tnks.